# Seems like DbContext and ASP.net Core Identity Services Are Singleton, not Scoped as documented

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

In my startup.cs file's `ConfigureServices` function, I have the following setup for my data context:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
   {
       options.UseSqlServer("Connection string");
   });
```

And then set up the identity service for it.

```
 services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext, int>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Everything works with DI. I am able to access `MyDbContext` and `UserManager<MyUser>` from my controllers, and obtain the data I need.

I am also under the impression (as I've read) that I get a new instance of `MyDbContext` **for every request**. I don't think that's what happens. `MyDbContext` seems to be a singleton.

In server A, I run this: `await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(aUser,"theirCurrentPassword");`

It returns true when I find the user and their password is correct.

On server B, I point to the same data context and also use the Identity service. On server B, I run `await userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(theSameUser, "theirCurrentPassword", "theirNewPassword")`. I know that this function works and recognizes the change, since when I run it again (from within server B), it will give me an error saying that "theirCurrentPassword" is wrong.

Now, back on server A, I run `userManager.CheckPasswordAsync` again, via a distinct API call, but this time, passing the new password "theirNewPassword". I am getting a 401 (wrong password). It will be successful if I put in "theirOldPassword", but I have already changed that user's password successfully on server B.

The only thing I can think of is that `MyDbContext` in server A is the same instance even across distinct HTTP requests, contrary to documentation. If I shut down server A, restart it, and make that same request, passing in "theirNewPassword", it will authenticate as expected. I can't be shutting down and restarting server A continuously.

I believe I've posted all relevant code necessary for my concern. If not, please let me know.

So how do I make sure that `MyDbContext` and the identity services have a Scoped, and not a Singleton lifetime?

Furthermore, how would I manually instantiate a data context and set up a `UserManager<MyUser>` explicitly inside a controller action (AKA, trying to avoid DI which seems to make my data context and identity services singletons).?

Comment: The AddEntityFrameworkStores extension method  adds only scoped  lifecycle registries https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs

Comment: Can you show the code where you inject and use that `userManager`?